# Refreshing Owl Carousel 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, eventtrigger, owl-carousel-2

I have 3 divs that activate slide toggle when I click on them. And inside every div there is owl carousel slider.

If I trigger one div the slider shows, but when I click other div slider doesn't show unless I resize the window.

How can I trigger refresh on slide toggle for the slider in every div?

I tried with this on slide toggle but it doesn't work:

```
$('.owl-slider').trigger('refresh.owl.carousel');
```

Comment: Can you write more code?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You trigger with a class. You can try with a variable:

```
var $owl = $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    items: 1,
    loop:true
});

$owl.trigger('refresh.owl.carousel');
```

Comment: For me this actually fixed some other issues related to screen resizing.

Answer (score 13):

if `$owl.trigger('refresh.owl.carousel');` didn't work with you, you can use

```js
window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
```

which will make the carousel refresh automatically.

Comment: Cool! I use Owl in React project so I had problem when after initialization my carousel with `items={`}` display with few items. I tried `$(window).trigger('resize');` but it's not worked. So I had played with this problem and soled it by added `onInitialized={window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));}`

Comment: Don't understand what these ginious are talking about. you should give any snippet, demo code,...

Answer (score 2):

I want to set new html content for my carousel and the above answers did not worked for me
so I solved my problem with another way

first, define a function to start owlCarousel and run that function

```
let myCarousel; //a variable thats hold owlCarousel object
function myCarouselStart() {
    myCarousel = $('#my-carousel.owl-carousel').owlCarousel(setting);
}

$(document).ready(() => {
    myCarouselStart(); // run owl carousel for first time
});
```

then when you want to refresh the carousel use the below code

```
 myCarousel.trigger("destroy.owl.carousel");
 $("#my-carousel").html(newHtmlContent);
 myCarouselStart();
```