# What event triggers the carousel rendering?

Tags: jquery, zurb-foundation, owl-carousel-2

Carousel init happens on DOM ready, but after I load the (Foundation) styles, than the carousel is broken. If I resize the window manually, than carousel is rendered fine. I tried to trigger:

```
$(window).trigger('resize');
```

but no success. Obviously the OWL reacts to some event, but I cannot find it.

I also tried:

```
$('.slick-slider-container').owlCarousel('refresh');
```

and

```
$('.slick-slider-container').owlCarousel('reinit');
```

but than is even worse (window resize helps no more).

The issue may be connected to Foundation framework, besides regular CSS rules I also have the Equilizer inside slides.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Refreshing Owl Carousel 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32347919/refreshing-owl-carousel-2)

Comment: Nope, it ain't working.