# after ajax success owl-carousel css and js file can not apply to my code

Tags: laravel

I uses  following method to product filter code is excute very well for apge loading but when i am sending some html code from controller to view and load using ajax call. It works but after success function. some function can not apply. when i am loading first time my website it works fine and some   owl-carousel,owl-theme, owl-loaded, classes apply to  div ps-shoe__variant normal but after ajax call it will not loaded and structure of div ps-shoe--variant is disturbed I am confused what happens ?? need solutions

view:

```
<div class="ps-product__columns">
    <div class="ps-shoe__content">
                      <div class="ps-shoe__variants">
                         <div class="ps-shoe__variant normal">
                                <?php
                                   $images=[]; 
                                   $images = explode(",",$product_data->product_multiple_image);
                                 ?>
                                 @foreach($images as $image)
                                  <img src="https://datamansolutions.in/ecommerce/images/{{$image}}" alt="">
                                 @endforeach
                              </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

controller:

```
  public function getDetails(Request $request)
    {
      $product = DB::table('table_subcategory')
        ->join('table_category','table_subcategory.category_id','=','table_category.category_id')
        ->join('table_product','table_subcategory.subcategory_id','=','table_product.subcategory_id')
        ->select('table_product.*','table_category.category_name','table_subcategory.subcategory_name')
        ->where('table_category.category_id',$request->cat_id) 
        ->get();
      $output='';
        foreach($product as $product_data)
          {

            
               $output .= '<div class="ps-shoe__content">';
               $output .= '<div class="ps-shoe__variants">';
               $output .= '<div class="ps-shoe__variant normal">';
               
                    foreach($images as $image)
                     {
                $output .='<img src="https://datamansolutions.in/ecommerce/images/'.$image.'" alt="">';
                     }
                             
                $output .='</div>';
                $output .= '</div>';
                $output .= '</div>';

            }

         echo $output;
    }
```

ajax:

```
$(document).on('click', '.category_li', function(){
var cat_id = $(this).attr("data-val");
//alert(sub_id);
    $.ajax({
    type : 'get',
    url : '/getDetails',
    data:{ 'cat_id': cat_id
    },
    success:function(data)
    {
        console.log(data);

        $('.ps-product__columns').html(data);
    }
});
});
```

Comment: I think you must refresh owl carousel for new data. see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32348314/3121398

Comment: @Enver no this is not working are you getting my problem?